# Restangular save and retry after refresh

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm working on an SPA that is usually online but can go offline and I have to keep a log of all requests to an API. When certain requests fail I should retry them later.

I've got a local DB to save all requests. When my app starts I retrieve them all and retry the ones marked to.

What I need is a way to config a Restangular object based on what I already sent. I have a response interceptor and I'm saving the restangular response object.

```
{
  config: {
    headers: Object,
    method: "GET",
    params: Object,
    transformRequest: Array[1],
    transformResponse: Array[1],
    url: "..."
  },
  data: {...},
  headers: {...},
  status: 200,
  statusText: "OK"
}
```

Is there a function to create a Restangular with the given config object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i would doing this i would setup setErrorInterceptor

```
var yourLocalDb = function($http) {
   var failedRequests = [];

   this.store = function(request) {
      this.failedRequests.push(request);
   }

   this.retry = function() {
     var self = this;
     angular.forEach(this.failedRequests,function(request) {
       $http(request.response.config).then(function() { 
        //in case of success
        self.failedRequests.splice(self.failedRequests.indexOf(request),1);
        request.responseHandler.apply(undefined,arguments);
       }), request.deferred.reject);
     });

   }
} 


Restangular.setErrorInterceptor(function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {

  yourLocalDb.store({
  response : response,
  responseHandler : responseHandler,
  deffered : deffered
  });
}
```

then when you have connection you can just call

```
yourLocalDb.retry();
```

Not tested, but it should give you clue.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I cannot test it anymore as I quit the project a few months back but before that I did something similar